# How to know if tablet or phone in Android

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a var in Swift like this :

```
@Published  var textFieldSize = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? 20.0 :  12.0
```

How can i get the same device type (phone or tablet) but in Jetpack Compose Android ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val expanded = configuration.screenWidthDp > 840
```

This corresponds to 97.22% of tablets in landscape. For sizes corresponding to phones or tablets there is more info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes).

Answer (score 8):

Following the answers of אריאל עדן and Code Poet, you can use this function:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun isTablet(): Boolean {
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    return if (configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        configuration.screenWidthDp > 840
    } else {
        configuration.screenWidthDp > 600
    }
}
```

And call it in your composables like:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val isTablet = isTablet()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works well but if you want to check if the display is a tablet in the portal mode you must enter a smaller number like 600, not 840.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better easier solution, check if the width size is medium or expanded then it is a tablet device other wise it is a compact which can be a phone.

```
@Composable
fun isTablet(): Boolean = when (getWindowWidthSize()) {
    WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium, WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded -> true
    else -> false
}
```

you may need to optin some expermental material 3 apis.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer from Quốc Hùng and Code Poet...

You could have a slightly nicer way of using the `isTablet` value by wrapping this in a `CompositionLocalProvider` like so:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun isTablet(): Boolean {
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    return if (configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        configuration.screenWidthDp > 1000
    } else {
        configuration.screenWidthDp > 750
    }
}

data class DeviceInfo(val isTablet: Boolean)

val LocalDeviceInfo = staticCompositionLocalOf<DeviceInfo> {
    error("No device information found")
}

@Composable
fun AppTheme(/*...*/) {
    // Theme set up stuff...
    val isTablet = isTablet()
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalDevice provides DeviceInfo(isTablet)) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colorScheme = colorScheme,
            typography = if (isTablet) TabletTypography else PhoneTypography,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

You would then use it like so:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyComponent() {
    val deviceInfo = LocalDeviceInfo.current

    if (deviceInfo.isTablet) {
        Text(text = "I'm a tablet!")
    } else {
        Text(text = "I'm a phone!")
    }
}
```

The documentation of `staticCompositionLocalOf` says:

> Create a CompositionLocal key that can be provided using CompositionLocalProvider.
> Unlike compositionLocalOf, reads of a staticCompositionLocalOf are not tracked by the composer and changing the value provided in the CompositionLocalProvider call will cause the entirety of the content to be recomposed instead of just the places where in the composition the local value is used. This lack of tracking, however, makes a staticCompositionLocalOf more efficient when the value provided is highly unlikely to or will never change. For example, the android context, font loaders, or similar shared values, are unlikely to change for the components in the content of a the CompositionLocalProvider and should consider using a staticCompositionLocalOf. A color, or other theme like value, might change or even be animated therefore a compositionLocalOf should be used.
> staticCompositionLocalOf creates a ProvidableCompositionLocal which can be used in a a call to CompositionLocalProvider. Similar to MutableList vs. List, if the key is made public as CompositionLocal instead of ProvidableCompositionLocal, it can be read using CompositionLocal.current but not re-provided.