How to observe the effect of staticCompositionLocalOf()?
I would like to observe how the use of staticCompositionLocalOf causes "the entirety of the content lambda of the CompositionLocalProvider to be recomposed" as per the androids.compose.runtime documentation:

Unlike compositionLocalOf, reads of a staticCompositionLocalOf are not tracked by the composer and changing the value provided in the CompositionLocalProvider call will cause the entirety of the content to be recomposed instead of just the places where in the composition the local value is used.

Running the attached code, I expected the Text composable in both setContent and in the Node composable, and the Node composable itself, to recompose when I clicked the Button. However Android Studio's Layer Inspector showed that only the Leaf and the Text composable in Leaf were recomposed.  As the attached screenshots show, changing staticCompositionLocalOf on line 2 of the code to compositionLocalOf resulted in the same recompositions. I have also tried counter = mutableStateOf(Counter()) with the type of LocalCounter appropriately updated, with no difference in results.


data class Counter (var count: MutableState<Int> = mutableStateOf(0))
val LocalCounter = staticCompositionLocalOf<Counter> {
    error("CompositionLocal LocalCounter not provided")
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private var counter = Counter()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalCounter provides counter) {
                Column {
                    Text("setContent ${LocalCounter}")
                    Node()
                    Button(content = { Text("+1") },
                        onClick = { counter.count.value += 1 }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Node() {
    Text("Node")
    Leaf()
}

@Composable
fun Leaf() {
    val counter = LocalCounter.current
    Text("Leaf count: ${counter.count.value}")
}

I've run the code using Android Studio Jellyfish Patch 1 with Pixel 8 API 34 emulator, Android Studio Koala Canary 2 with Pixel 8 API VanillaIceCream emulator and physical Pixel 4a running API 33. All with Kotlin 1.9.24 and all with the same recompositions.
Related questions on stackoverflow, and the web at large, mostly asked about the usage of CompositionLocal, such as How and when exactly CompositionLocal sets values implicitly? or https://stackoverflow.com/a/77496284, or about the conceptual difference between staticCompositionLocalOf and compositionLocalOf, which the official documentation explains. I couldn't find any example code showing how the difference between these two can be shown.
Any example to show recomposition of composable that does not use the value provided, but due solely to the use of staticCompositionLocalOf, would be much appreciated!
Updated code based on Jan Itor's answer:
In one of my original failed attempts, instead of observing provided value of type Counter, I tried to observe provided value of type MutableState<Counter> and updating the Counter in the mutable value when clicking Button. Here're the diffs, with a non-mutable property in the data class:
# line 1:
data class Counter(var count: Int = 0)
# line 2:
val LocalCounter = staticCompositionLocalOf<MutableState<Counter>> {
# line 6:
private var counter = mutableStateOf(Counter())
# line 18:
onClick = { counter.value = Counter(counter.value.count + 1) }
# line 35:
Text("Leaf count: ${counter.value.count}")

The resulting recompositions were the same as the original code. My current understanding is that while counter.value has been updated, counter itself has not--the CompositionLocal value still contains the same pointer to the same box, the instance of Counter in the box has changed, but the box and the pointer to it are still the same. The CompositionLocal thus did not detect any change.
To see the effect of staticCompositionLocalOf, the value inside the CompositionLocal box itself has to change. Here's the updated code:
data class Counter(var count: Int = 0)
val LocalCounter = staticCompositionLocalOf<Counter> {
    error("CompositionLocal LocalCounter not provided")
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private var counter = mutableStateOf(Counter())

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalCounter provides counter.value) {
                Column {
                    Text("setContent ${LocalCounter}")
                    Node()
                    Button(content = { Text("+1") },
                        onClick = { counter.value = Counter(counter.value.count + 1) }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Node() {
    Text("Node")
    Leaf()
}

@Composable
fun Leaf() {
    val counter = LocalCounter.current
    Text("Leaf count: ${counter.count}")
}

(Using property delegation with by on line 6 obviates the need to refer to .value on lines 13 and 18, for cleaner syntax, but I wanted to be explicit about the types involved.)

To elaborate on the official documentation, my summary is that if the observed mutable state is a member of a class but the instance of the class provided by CompositionLocal itself doesn't change often, use of staticCompositionLocalOf prevents tracking of the provided (slow changing) instance. On the other hand, if the provided instance itself changes frequently, use of compositionLocalOf prevents recomposition of composables not observing the provided instance. Examples of the former: the original Counter above, or collections where individual elements are mutable, and observed, but the collection instances themselves are slow changing. Examples of the latter: replacing whole instances of basic types, String, collections, or custom classes.

When you update the CompositionLocal value like this: counter.count.value += 1 it doesn't really change the value provided in the CompositionLocalProvider call. The instance of Counter stays the same, only its property changes.
When CompositionLocal is able to track updates to its value like it this example:
private val LocalCount = compositionLocalOf { 0 }
private var count by mutableIntStateOf(0)

private val LocalCountStatic = staticCompositionLocalOf { 0 }
private var countStatic by mutableIntStateOf(0)

@Composable
fun CompositionLocalTest() {
    Column {
        Text("Outer text")
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalCount provides count,
            LocalCountStatic provides countStatic,
        ) {
            Column {
                Text("Inner text")
                Text("LocalCount ${LocalCount.current}")
                Text("LocalCountStatic ${LocalCountStatic.current}")

                Node()

                Button(
                    onClick = { count = Random.nextInt(1000) }
                ) { Text("Change LocalCount") }
                Button(
                    onClick = { countStatic = Random.nextInt(1000) }
                ) { Text("Change LocalCountStatic") }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Node() {
    Text("Node")
    Leaf()
}

@Composable
fun Leaf() {
    Text("Leaf count: ${LocalCount.current}")
    Text("Leaf count static: ${LocalCountStatic.current}")
}

Clicking on the top button will lead to a partial recompose:

While updating staticCompositionLocalOf will recompose the entirety of the content lambda:


Thank you!  I managed to adopt your answer to my data class Counter and got it to work. I will post the updated code as an update to my question.
